# "There are neither" or "there are no neither"?

Tags: usage

If I'm a seller and someone asks me: "Are there rice and beans in your store?" and then I could answer in one of the following options:

> a) There are **no** neither.
>
> b) There are neither.
>
> c) There are neither, rice or beans.
>
> d) There are **no** neither, rice or beans.

What is correct English among the above options?

(there are two points in my question: **1**. if I have to add the word "no" after neither. **2**. If I have to complete the sentece after "neither", or it's enough to say neither).

Comment: As an aside, "answer me" means "give to me an answer to a question that I asked." Since the question was asked to you by someone else, you may say _I could answer him_ or _I could answer her._

Comment: You could also say, "I'm sorry, but we have neither at this time."

Comment: @DavidK K. it's absolutely typo:) Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Honestly, though, I think 'we have neither', or - even more likely - 'I'm sorry, but we don't have either [of those/them]' would be more idiomatic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Standard English, a double negative (when it is permitted)
is a "positive": the two negative meanings cancel each other out.
The word *neither* has a negative meaning,
and since you mean to convey a negative meaning you should not
combine the word *neither* with another "negative" word such as *no.*

It is also conventional to use the connector *nor* rather than *or*
when listing the items to which the word *neither* applies.
Hence you could say you have neither rice nor beans.
Notice that there is no comma between the word *neither*
and the list of things whose existence it denies.

Hence we see that option a) has an error, option c) has two errors,
and option d) has three.

That leaves only option b).
It is permitted to omit the list of items after the word *neither*
in cases where it will be understood what things were meant.
Since you were asked if you had rice or beans in your store, 
it is correct to say that you have neither.
You can also say, "There are neither,"
where it is understood that it is rice and beans that do not exist
and that your store is the place where they do not exist.

Comment: IMO it sounds best with a no at the beginning: "No, there are neither [rice nor beans]."

Comment: @Kat That's a good point. "No," by itself, is an answer, and the rest of the sentence gives the answer again in greater detail. That is fine; it provides emphasis to the statement. Using "no" in this way does _not_ constitute a double negative.

Answer (score 2):

> ***There are neither rice nor beans*.**

That is the only sentence which makes sense and should be correct.